# NewRelic Ruby Agent: errors not ignored

Tags: ruby, sidekiq, newrelic

In a Sidekiq worker I want to ignore some errors in NewRelic while still raising them so that Sidekiqs retry behaviour kicks in.
I wrote a helper class to call `NewRelic::Agent.ignore_transaction` but still NewRelic reports these exceptions and complains about the error rate. What am I doing wrong?
I guess that I may have misunderstood something about the scope of the transaction?

```
module NewRelic
  # Run a block which rescues some exceptions and ignores them in NewRelic
  class IgnoreExceptions
    class << self
      def ignore(*class_list)
        raise ArgumentError, 'Block required' unless block_given?
        begin
          yield
        rescue errors_matching { |e| class_list.include?(e.class) }
          NewRelic::Agent.ignore_transaction
          raise
        end
      end

      private

      def errors_matching(&block)
        Module.new.tap { |m| m.define_singleton_method(:===, &block) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to ignore the transaction you may be better off targeting the errors being generated. If there is a specific error class you would like the New Relic Ruby agent to ignore you could utilize the `error_collector.ignore_errors` [configuration option](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/installation-configuration/ruby-agent-configuration#error_collector). Another possible solution would be to use the [`NewRelic::Agent#ignore_error_filter`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/newrelic/rpm/NewRelic/Agent:ignore_error_filter) method to filter the errors the agent is tracking.

Comment: Ah, the `ignore_error_filter` is indeed much better suited. Seems like I overlooked it before. Thanks a lot!